# Node.js server hosting with oracledb

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I am developing using mac

I want to create a node.js server to access the oracle database from the iPhone app.

The localhost has successfully accessed the Oracle database via the node.js server.

However, I was faced with an error in hosting it. (Hosting used firebase hosting.)

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>   Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 9.8.0 (darwin, x64)
>   Node.js require() error was: 
>     DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#macos for help
>   Node.js require() mapped to /Users/jeongyeon/Atom/BestianServer/functions/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node
>   Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html

To use oracledb in node.js, oracle instantclient must have a symbolic linked(ln-s)
**On Windows, environment variables must be set.

I think that when hosted I get an error because I do not recognize the symbolic link or environment variable setting.

Has anyone succeeded in hosting oracledb on nodejs?
I would appreciate a little help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you host it on Linux instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variables for it.

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Comment: I've already set up a symbolic link in mac(Concepts like setting environment variables in Windows) and have successfully accessed the Oracle database on my local host.
However, I was faced with an error in hosting it.

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/910 do you think it's the node version?

Comment: I do not think this is a node version issue because it runs successfully on the local host.
But I will change the node version and try again.

Comment: I tested it now on Windows and received a Mac-like error message.
This window also works successfully on the local host.

The node version of this window is 6.14.0. It certainly does not seem to be a problem with node version.

The hosting error message is as follows
>Detailed stack trace: Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 6.14.0 (linux, x64)
Node.js require() error was:
  DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"